# How to make a python program to decrypt caesar cipher without key? (Frequency analysis)

Tags: python, cryptography, caesar-cipher

I have no clue how to do this can someone help me start and guide me write a program to decrypt the caesar encrypted text. I have a program which decrypts and prints all 26 shifts, but I want to print only one right one, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

**Edit after seeing the mention of the term 'frequency analysis' in the question.**

You can do this two ways, depending upon the kind of text you have to decipher.

**Frequency Analysis**
If your text is decently long, then it can be done by frequency analysis. Every english alphabet has certain frequency of occurring (for an example [here](http://pi.math.cornell.edu/~mec/2003-2004/cryptography/subs/frequencies.html)). You know your most frequent letter in the encrypted text is likely to be E, T or A. You can substitute one letter at a time and see if 'words' skeleton starts to emerge. This will be a trial and error until the text is decrypted. Alternatively you can match the letters, in your encrypted text, with that of plain english letters depending upon the 'nearest' frequency of match.
Your task will become harder if there are no spaces between the words (but I guess since you are dealing with simple Caesar cipher, that possibility is less).

**Look up into English dictionary**

If you do not have long enough text or a text whose pattern of letter usage is skewed w.r.t. 'usual' english, then I would have done as below. Please note this method will mean that you have access to English dictionary for a look up.

You can feed all the words (that are generated for each shift) into an english dictionary lookup. You can give +1 score if a match is found for every word or -1 otherwise. The correct shift will have maximum scores. This is more automated and comparatively less trial and error.

Please note this method will also need to be adjusted, if your encrypted text has no whitespace between the words.

Please let us know more about the kind of encrypted text you have and if you are required to use frequency analysis only.

Comment: Yes I can use an english dictionary. Wait can you please like ellaborate, how would I feed all the words? Thank you for the contribution :)

Comment: I will not have access to a computer before evening, so I can't give you an example. However I have expanded my answer.

Comment: No I do not have to use frequency analysis only, but I thought that was the easiest method to decipher if you do not have the key. I am just looking for the easiest and simplest method at the moment... Appreciate your effort :)

Comment: What's wrong with the current answer, did you *try* frequency analysis already? It seems it takes more time for you to talk about this answer than that you spend typing code...

Comment: But I don't know where to start. I have a program which lists all the 26 possible shiifts but I need to print only one correct one

Comment: @TrialAcc the easiest way to do that is to check for English (Or your language) in the message, and print the one with the most matches to words in the dictionary. Also, there really isn't any point doing Freq analysis on the Ceasar shift cipher; it is many times faster to brute force it